# SQL Left join Many to Many, only display distinct ID in left table

Tags: php, mysql, join

TableA

```
ID Name
1   Peter
2   Mary
3   John
```

TableB

```
ID Event
1  eventA
2  eventB
3  eventC
```

TableC

```
ID aID bID
1  1 1
2  1 3
3  2 1
```

I am doing like this

```
Select Distinct a.ID, b.ID
From tableA as a
Left Join tableC as c
On a.ID = c.aID
Left Join tableB as b
On c.bID = b.ID
```

It shows

```
1 Peter eventA
1 Peter eventC
```

I want the output as follows

```
1 Peter eventA
        eventC
```

How could I do that? Many thanks.

---

Amendment:

Actually displaying the records like the below:

1 Peter
eventA
eventC

From suggestion it works fine, but I wanna add hide show function.

function ReverseDisplay(d) {

if(document.getElementById(d).style.display == "none") {

document.getElementById(d).style.display = "block"; }

else { document.getElementById(d).style.display = "none"; }

}

Select Distinct a.ID, b.ID, b.Event

From tableA as a

Left Join tableC as c

On a.ID = c.aID

Left Join tableB as b

On c.bID = b.ID

```
$lastId = "";
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs))
{   
    if ($lastId != $row[0]){
        echo "<a href='javascript:ReverseDisplay(" . ($row[0]) . ")'>" . $row[0] . "</a>";  
        echo urldecode($row[1])." ";    
        $lastId = $row[0];
        echo "<br/>";

        //id needs to be unique to match javascript function
        echo "<div id=" . ($row[0]) . " style='display:none;'>";
    }

    echo $row[2];   

    //that's the problem, </div> must print only one time when in the last loop of same a.id, but how???
    echo "</div>"   

}
```

If I add count function

Select Distinct a.ID, b.ID, b.Event, count(a.id)

From tableA as a

Left Join tableC as c

On a.ID = c.aID

Left Join tableB as b

On c.bID = b.ID

It only shows

1 Peter

eventA

// could not show eventC

// it loops one time only

Could anyone help? I have tried for days but failed. Many thanks.

Comment: You can't get the given output by `SQL query` or `join` you may need to first fetch your query output then prepare html to show this output. 
Hint: you will be need to use php `in_array()`

Comment: just a suggestion, try `GROUP_CONCAT` to fetch data like `1 Peter eventA,eventC`

Comment: BTW, your question is very confusing as your data setm your query, and your result set do not correspond with one another.

Answer (score 3):

This is an output (HTML) formatting issue, not an SQL issue.  (You could theoretically construct a really complicated query using subqueries, cases and nulls, but there's really no need to go to all that trouble.)

If you execute this query (note the ORDER BY):

```
Select Distinct a.ID, a.Name, b.Event
From tableA as a
Left Join tableC as c
On a.ID = c.aID
Left Join tableB as b
On c.bID = b.ID
ORDER BY a.ID
```

Then in your PHP:

```
// I'm assuming you're using MySQLi in an OO fashion, but
// you can adjust this as needed.  Also, I'm missing out
// all the HTML (except a <BR>) - you can add in whatever
// HTML formatting you require as per your desired layout
$lastId = null; // remember the last person ID we had
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    if ($lastId != $row('ID') {
        // different person, so show their name:
        echo $row('Name');
        // and update $lastId 
        $lastId = $row('ID');
    }
    // show the event and move to the next line:
    echo $row('Event') . '<br>';
}
```

Comment: I suspect that it would be more usual not to spit the array out as a bit of json and then use javascript and css to do the formatting - but the principle's essentially the same as you describe above, so +1

Answer (score 1):

I agree that problems like this are best handled in the presentation layer (e.g. a simple PHP loop), but just for fun...

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS table_a;

CREATE TABLE table_a
(id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
,name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL UNIQUE
);

INSERT INTO table_a VALUES
(1,'Peter'),
(2,'Mary'),
(3,'John');

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS table_b;

CREATE TABLE table_b
(id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
,event VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL UNIQUE
);

INSERT INTO table_b VALUES
(1,'eventA'),
(2,'eventB'),
(3,'eventC');

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS table_c;

CREATE TABLE table_c
(a_id INT NOT NULL 
,b_id INT NOT NULL
,PRIMARY KEY(a_id,b_id)
);

INSERT INTO table_c VALUES
(1,1),
(1,3),
(2,1);

SELECT CASE WHEN a.id = @prev THEN '' ELSE a.id END a_id
     , CASE WHEN a.id = @prev THEN '' ELSE a.name END name
     , b.event
     , @prev := a.id
  FROM table_a a
  LEFT 
  JOIN table_c c
    ON c.a_id = a.id 
  LEFT
  JOIN table_b b
    ON b.id = c.b_id
 CROSS
  JOIN (SELECT @prev := null) vars
 ORDER 
    BY a.id, b.id; 

+------+-------+--------+---------------+
| a_id | name  | event  | @prev := a.id |
+------+-------+--------+---------------+
| 1    | Peter | eventA |             1 |
|      |       | eventC |             1 |
| 2    | Mary  | eventA |             2 |
| 3    | John  | NULL   |             3 |
+------+-------+--------+---------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't achieve that using SQL. You have to format that output on another level - when displaying output. But you can sort retrieved records using SQL to have less work in PHP.

Because I can't comment I'll not recommend using PHP `in_array()` function too often because it pretty slow when compared with keyed array (you can define array which key will be value you're searching for and value eg. true and then look to that array just by index and testing value if its true).

```
$used_values = array()
$used_values[$value] = true;
```

test:

```
if ($used_values[$value] === true).....
```

Comment: You *can* achieve this using SQL, but I agree that problems of data display are best handled in a presentation layer/application level code.

Comment: Truth, but I'll not go for that. It's too expensive (= time consuming) to achieve this on SQL server. I think thats not solvable using simple select, but you have to write some kind of stored procedure/function.

Answer (score 0):

Another vote for doing it in the presentation layer, but out of amusement another way to do it in a single SQL query.

```
SELECT IF(b.id = min_bid OR min_bid IS NULL, a.id, ''), 
        IF(b.id = min_bid OR min_bid IS NULL, a.name, ''), 
        b.event
FROM table_a a
LEFT OUTER JOIN table_c c ON c.a_id = a.id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN table_b b ON b.id = c.b_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(
    SELECT a.id, MIN(b.id) AS min_bid
    FROM table_a a
    INNER JOIN table_c c ON c.a_id = a.id 
    INNER JOIN table_b b ON b.id = c.b_id
    GROUP BY a_id
) sub0
ON a.id = sub0.id
ORDER BY a.id, b.id
```